# Angular2 - Injetar Componente ao Body

Tags: angular, component

Boa tarde!

Tenho o seguinte componente

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, HostListener, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
/**
 * This class represents the navigation bar component.
 */

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-notification',
  templateUrl: 'notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['notification.component.css'],
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() mensagem: string;
  @Input() time: number = 2000;
  @Input() tipo: string ="";
  isVisible = true;
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ngOnDestroy();
    }, this.time);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.isVisible = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.nativeElement.remove();
    }, 1000);
  }

  private _timeOut: number = 3000;
  public get timeOut(): number {
    return this._timeOut;
  }
  public set timeOut(v: number) {
    this._timeOut = v;
  }

  fechar() {
    this.ngOnDestroy();
  }
}
```

Quero injetar ele dentro de outro Component, em javascript seria algo assim:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
/**
 * This class represents the lazy loaded ServicoComponent.
 */
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-servico',
  templateUrl: 'servico.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['servico.component.css']
})
export class ServicoComponent {

  constructor(public service: ServicoService) {
  }

  salvar(servico?: Servico) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<sd-notification tipo="syo-success" mensagem="Dados salvos com sucesso!"></sd-notification>'; // Mas isso não compila a diretiva ds-notification.... 
  }

}
```

Porem com o Angular2 não compila essa diretiva.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, para você injetar este componente dentro de outro é necessário utilizar uma feature do angular2 que pode ser observada em detalhe neste [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) do site oficial.

Para compilar o componente é preciso utilizar o método `createComponent` da classe `ViewContainerRef` contida em '@angular/core'.
Este método recebe como parametro um `ComponentFactory<T>` que pode ser obtido das seguintes formas:

**1 -** Método `resolveComponentFactory` da classe `ComponentFactoryResolver` ('@angular/core') que recebe como parâmetro o tipo do componente, no seu caso seria `NotificationComponent`.

**2 -** Utilizando algum dos métodos presentes na classe `Compiler` ('@angular/core'), sendo mais comum a utilização do `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` que recebe como parâmetro o modulo do componente a ser "injetado".

Em resumo, podemos dizer que o `ViewContainerRef` seria uma referencia do local aonde você irá injetar o componente utilizando uma das duas formas apresentadas acima. Você pode observar como ficaria utilizando `ComponenteFactoryResolver` no exemplo abaixo:

```
export class InjetorComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private _vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      //Destrói todas as views injetadas neste componente.
      this._vcRef.clear();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NotificationComponent);
    let componentRef = this._vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    //Acessando a instancia do componente.
    (<NotificationComponent>componentRef.instance).menssagem = "Menssagem de um componente criado dinamicamente!";
  }
}
```

Algumas referências com o conteúdo a respeito do assunto (links do stackoverflow.com).

[How do I dynamically inject an Angular2 sub component via typescript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618222/how-do-i-dynamically-inject-an-angular2-sub-component-via-typescript-code)

[How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009)